# Creating a Top Ten list in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been searching for a way to make a "Top Ten" list for my uncles hockey league in Excel.

There are 5 different teams with their own worksheets and I made a separate worksheet called "data" referencing all of the players and their individual stats so that I could pull my "Top Ten" from one worksheet instead of five.

The worksheet is setup as follows:

```
    Player1  Player2  Player3  etc... 
Name

Team

Goals

Assists

Points
```

I would like to search for the player with the highest number of "Points" and return the name, team, goals, assists, and points on a single row, and then move down for the next player, i.e.:

```
Name 1    Team     Goals     Assists    Points

Name 2    Team     Goals     Assists    Points
```

I have tried using multiple ways including index and hlookup with the large and match commands, but could not get anything to work. 
I feel like I am missing something simple here.

If it would be easier to have the players in rows, I could do that.
I was just having a problem with my references filling in the way I wanted them to.

Comment: HNY, Bob! I noticed you had an extra question about the ranking on the sheet. Thought of it: take a look to the example sheet, link the same as in answer. Thanks for making to think out of the box :-)

Comment: Thank you Juri. It looks like you edited the original answer as well which also answers how to sort by points and then goals which I hadn't realized was a problem until now! I had asked a similar question on how to sort teams by points and then by goals for and I think this will cover that as well. I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help. Thanks again and again! Oh, and HNY to you too!

Comment: I managed to read your question and then it disappeared somewhere without a trace. However, I was a little bit too hooked ;-) I quite like the trick with dividing by 1000. Using RANK with the last optional number (switching ascending/descending order), it's possible to make the calculations even simpler and omit the number of players. Anyway, sleep time now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial table:
`B1`: `=COUNTA(B6:O6)`(the number of players)
`B6:O6` Name
`B7:O7` Team
`B8:O8` Goals
`B9:O9` Assists
`B10:O10` Points

Formulae below determine the rank for the player. If the score of points are equal, the player having a greater number of goals ranks higher.
`B4`:  `=$B$1-RANK(B$10;$B$10:$O$10)+B8/1000`, the formula is copied to the right. The result will be fractional numbers with equal integer parts for the equal amount of points.
`B3`: `=RANK(B4;$B$4:$O$4)`, the formula is copied to the right
`B2`: `=IF(COUNTIF(C$3:$O$3;B3)>0;B3+COUNTIF(C$3:$O$3;B3);B$3)`

Ranked table:
`A15` and down : Rank (1,2...n)
`B15` and down : `=HLOOKUP(A15;$A$2:$O$3;2;FALSE)`

In the next columns: `Name (col C), Goals (col D), Assists (col E), Points (col F)`

`C15`: `=HLOOKUP($A15;$A$2:$O$10;5;FALSE)`
`D15`: `=HLOOKUP($A15;$A$2:$O$10;7;FALSE)`
`E15`: `=HLOOKUP($A15;$A$2:$O$10;8;FALSE)`
`F15`: `=HLOOKUP($A15;$A$2:$O$10;9;FALSE)`

Formulae in `B11:E11` will be copied down.

Example spreadsheet: http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Top_players_matrix_transposed.xls

Comment: Thank you both for your time! Once I have the table recreated, I will append the worksheet name to the cell values and go from there.

Comment: Update. Formula works exactly as I had hoped for. I am having trouble copying the cells down (the values will not change), but I will look into that. The hardest part is over though!

Comment: Is there any way to deal with duplicates? For instance, I have 3 players ranked as #5, but only one will show at a time...

Comment: Yes, I noticed it myself. Do all players with equal points have the equal rank?

Comment: I appears so. There are three ranked 5 and then it skips to 8 (no 6th and 7th rank). Ironically, all three have 6 goals and 5 assists...

Comment: No problem. Thank you again for your time and effort.

Comment: Take a look to  http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Top_players_matrix_transposed.xls
I made up some more helper cells (pink), they can be hidden afterwards.

Comment: You, my friend, are awesome! This looks to be exactly what i need, but it will be a little while before I can try it out. Thanks again!

Comment: I discovered a flaw in a formula for Rank 2, please reload the file.

Comment: I was finally able to get back to it. I had to modify the IF statement a little to allow for more than 2 of the same ranks, but other than that, it works great. Here is the file with the change i made: [http://www.filezoid.com/files/temp/Top_players_matrix_transposed (1).xls]

Comment: Thanks! Actually the last uploaded version had exactly the same modification you made, I discovered the flaw a little bit late :-)

Answer (score 0):

you have to **transpose the table** first..

- select all the rows and columns of your table.
- right click the first cell where you want to paste the table
- click paste special option
- check the transpose check-box in the dialog-box opened.

your table is now transposed. **now simple sorting** can give u answer

for sorting columns :

- select the whole table and click on the sort option on menu bar,

now you can retrieve all 10 top teams from this sorted list.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response! I was trying to transpose the data, but it wouldn't paste properly for me. I also just noticed that I somehow have everything in that worksheet linked to another workbook, so I will have to recreate it anyhow. Also, and I apologize for not stating this earlier, I need to have the top ten list in it's own worksheet so that it can be distributed and printed on it's own.